# Python tkinter Buttons won't go below Labels

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am currently working on a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game to learn about the GUI capabilities of Python (I'm working with Tkinter). I want to place the labels above the buttons, somewhat as a title. But when I run the code, for some reason the button appears above the labels. To fix this, I tried to change the row of the labels to be above the button (**mL row = 0, sL row = 1**, and **button row = 2**), but when I did this, the button just disappeared.

```
from tkinter import *    

# Create the GUI (set title)
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")  # Create game announcer

gA = "X Goes First"
# Create Button List
buttons = []


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create Board Class
class Board(Frame):
'''Creates Game Board'''

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Board, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Creates Widgets (Buttons,labels,ext)
    def create_widgets(self):
        # main label
        mL = Label(text="Tic Tac Toe", font=("Comic Sans MS", "44"), padx=50, pady=50)
        mL.grid()
        # game announcer
        sL = Label(text=gA, font=("Comic Sans MS", "20"))
        sL.grid()
        # buttons
        r = 2  # row variable
        c = 0  # column variable
        self.c_button(0, r, c)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Creates the button and appends to buttons list
    def c_button(self, index, r, c):
        buttons.append(Button(self, font=("Comic Sans MS", "22"), width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.button_press(index)))
        buttons[index].grid(row=r)
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Acts when Button is pressed (for testing, changes color to red and adds text)
    def button_press(self,index):
        buttons[index].configure(bg="red",text="press")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main
board = Board(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

I tried to make the code as traceable as possible.

Comment: Use either buttons or labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that because of the way you invoke `Label` and `Button`, sometimes you're adding the element to the `Frame` you're creating and sometimes your adding it to the top level window:

```
mL = Label(text="Tic Tac Toe", ...)
sL = Label(text=gA, ...)
Button(self, font=("Comic Sans MS", "22"), ...)
```

These should all start the same:

```
mL = Label(self, text="Tic Tac Toe", ...)
sL = Label(self, text=gA, ...)
Button(self, font=("Comic Sans MS", "22"), ...)
```

Below is my rework of your code with this change as well as some other modifications to get rid of the interface globals and make them part of the object:

```
from tkinter import *

TITLE_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", "44")
BUTTON_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", "22")
ANNOUNCER_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", "20")

# Create Board Class
class Board(Frame):
    ''' Create Tic-Tac-Toe Game Board '''

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.buttons = [None] * 9
        self.sL = None
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack()

    # Create Widgets (buttons, labels, etc.)
    def create_widgets(self):
        # main label
        Label(self, text="Tic Tac Toe", font=TITLE_FONT, padx=50, pady=50).grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
        # game announcer
        self.sL = Label(self, text="X Goes First", font=ANNOUNCER_FONT)
        self.sL.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
        # buttons
        for r in range(3):  # row variable
            for c in range(3):  # column variable
                self.c_button(r * 3 + c, r + 2, c)

    # Create the button and appends to buttons list
    def c_button(self, index, r, c):
        self.buttons[index] = Button(self, font=BUTTON_FONT, width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.button_press(index))
        self.buttons[index].grid(row=r, column=c)

    # Act when Button is pressed (for testing, changes color to red and adds text)
    def button_press(self, index):
        self.buttons[index].configure(bg="red", text="press")
        self.sL['text'] = index

# Create the GUI
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

board = Board(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was missing something small